# Normalizing average scores resulted from different number of votes

Tags: mean, ranking

Imagine a contest, with 30 contestants, and 40 judges. Each judge had to rate them from 0-3, and the average score of each participant will be calculated. But not all participants were rated by all of the judges. I.e. One average score resulted from 25 votes, another from 40 votes, the other from 33, and, etc.

I have a dataset consisting of 30 average scores in the same range 0-3, but each resulted from a different number of votes. My question is how to standardize/normalize (don't know the right term) the average scores? For example (the highest score of 2.72 was the result of 20 votes, but another's with 2.52 was the result of 40 votes)

Comment: I suppose the goal is to rank the contestants ...